# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited.need

Tags: django, django-forms

I am facing error that i cant make form with field or exculde attribute please help me out to fix this error
code from forms.py is :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CustomerRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
    {'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password (again)', 
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    email = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form- 
    control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fiedls = ['email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2']
        labels = {'email': 'Email'}
        widgets = {'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a typo on `fiedls` when it should be `fields`